# In Rails, can't I use .next_week with -.hours?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to use `.next_week` not `+1.week`. Because the `.next_week` make the date next week and Monday at the same time. It's so comfortable. And then I subtract some hours. But nothing has been changed. Here's my code.

```
newDate = DateTime.now
newDate = newDate.next_week - 3.hours
=> Sun, 30 Aug 2015 21:00:00 +0900
newDate = newDate.next_week - 3.hours
=> Sun, 30 Aug 2015 21:00:00 +0900
newDate = newDate.next_week - 3.hours
=> Sun, 30 Aug 2015 21:00:00 +0900
```

Why they can't be used same time? Please explain to me. Thanks.

Comment: please clarify what you are expecting

Comment: you are rolling back the week by subtracting hours so next week will still be the following monday. e.g. `#next_week #=> monday - 3.hours #=> sunday #next_week (Same Monday)` it's just creating a cycle.

Comment: `+1.week` add 1 week the date obviously. But `.next_week` make the next week and Monday. I think it's comfortable. And I should not use it. But I just curious why the date is not changed.

Comment: `newDate.next_week` returns the same thing each time, then you subtract three hours from it to get back to where you started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `#next_week` and `- 3.hours` working at the same time. It is a misunderstanding about how `#next_week` works.

`#next_week` assumes by default a week is Monday-Sunday. This means when calling just `#next_week` it will return the next Monday at 00:00:00:00.

Example:

```
DateTime.now.next_week
#=> Mon, 03 Aug 2015 00:00:00 -0400
```

Okay so that make sense. Now you are substracting `3.hours` making it Sunday again

```
DateTime.now.next_week - 3.hours 
#=> Sun, 02 Aug 2015 21:00:00 -0400
```

Still makes perfect sense. Now here is where the confusion is. Since you rolled back to Sunday by subtracting `3.hours` the `#next_week` is the following Monday again so

```
(DateTime.now.next_week - 3.hours).next_week
#=> Mon, 03 Aug 2015 00:00:00 -0400
```

I hope this helps you understand the situation a bit better.

If you use `+ 1.week` this will take you to the same exact point in time the following week

```
  DateTime.now + 1.week
  #=> Fri, 07 Aug 2015 09:01:17 -0400
```

This does not rely on a weekly calendar but rather the basic math of adding 7 days to the referenced Date object.

In conclusion while `#next_week` might be comfortable you need to understand what it actually implies and I think I would prefer `+ 1.week` in this case for its flexibility and its lack of assumption.

There are also many other methods for traversing time through [ActiveSupport](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.0.0/DateAndTime/Calculations) such as `#advance`, `#days_since`, `weeks_since`, etc.

Final note `next_week` can accept a day parameter as well e.g

```
DateTime.now.next_week(:tuesday)
#=> Tue, 04 Aug 2015 00:00:00 -0400
DateTime.now.next_week(:thursday)
#=> Thu, 06 Aug 2015 00:00:00 -0400
```

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect answer.